# F# functions vs C# "Func"tions

Tags: c#, f#

So I ran across this tour of F#: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/tour

... and boy howdy is F# interesting! The very beginning of the tour defined a sample function, which looks pretty straightforward:

```
/// You use 'let' to define a function. This one accepts an integer argument and returns an integer. 
/// Parentheses are optional for function arguments, except for when you use an explicit type annotation.
let sampleFunction1 x = x*x + 3
```

So this makes sense to me. It defines what the function is so if I were to pass some number into this thing, it squares it and adds 3 to that result, as seen by the next line in the tour:

```
 /// Apply the function, naming the function return result using 'let'. 
/// The variable type is inferred from the function return type.
let result1 = sampleFunction1 4573
```

After giving this a few more minutes of thought, I came up with the conclusion that C# can do this too! I sure do love C# a whole lot. This is what the above would look like in C# as far as I can tell:

```
        Func<int, int> sampleFunction1 = x => x*x + 3;
        var result = sampleFunction1(4573);
```

So my main question is, what is the difference between what I wrote in C# and what the F# tour showed me? Sub-questions are: Is the IL code any different even though it's the same CLR? What are a few reasons I would use F# over C#?

Comment: The IL would likely be different just because the compilers are working with completely different languages and therefore have different optimizations, interpretations, translations, etc. You would need to find someone intimately familiar with both languages to tell you exactly how different in what way, but with an IL disassembler tool (such as [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/)), you can easily open up the executables/DLLs and explore for yourself.

Comment: You will not notice much difference in one liner functions. In fact many calls to the .NET BCL will exactly look the same in both C# and F#. However if you build something more complicated you will start seeing the advantages of F#, both from a syntax and structure perspective. Especially if you want to move away from an OO paradigm and decrease the mutable (moving) parts in your project.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Technically, these are equivalent. The IL might be a tad different, just because these are different compilers, but not much. In essence these are compiled in the same way.

But C# can't do *exactly* that. Did you notice how you had to write `Func<int,int>` in front? But that's just a very small toy function. What would happen in more practical cases? Observe:

```
// F#
let f x m = Map.find (x, x+1) m |> Seq.map ((+) 1)

// C#
Func<int, IDictionary<Tuple<int, int>, IEnumerable<int>>, IEnumerable<int>> f = (x, m) => m[Tuple.Create(x, x+1)].Select( i => i+1 );
```

Fun, isn't it?
This is called "type inference". As in, F# is able to *infer* types of stuff based on how stuff is used. You can almost write a full program and never once use a type annotation. C# has this too, to some limited extent. That's how I'm able to call `.Select( i => i+1 )`, and C# knows that `i` is `int`, because whatever came before `.Select` was `IEnumerable<int>`. But it's very limited, not nearly as powerful.

Type inference is just *one* of the many benefits of F#. I picked it, because you were looking right at it and not seeing it. But there are many more. Order of compilation, lack of nulls, immutability by default, algebraic data types, automatic currying and partial application... Much more, in fact, than will fit in a SO answer.

Those who wish to discover the wonderful and exciting world of functional programming in general and F# in particular, I usually send right off to https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/, into Mr. Wlaschin's kind and capable hands. A wonderful resource, read it all.

Comment: I noted the immutability in the tour and I liked that quite a bit! I also like your example for how awful the func looks in C#. Do you have any insight as to how this may change with the new Tuple stuff in C# 7?

Comment: Not much. It'll make the type notation a bit shorter, but you'd still have to write it. The thing with C# is, no matter how many shiny features it gets, you can't fix some of the fundamental problems (e.g. nulls, mutability) without breaking old code. And if you're breaking old code, then that's a new language, in which case you could just as well move to F#.

Comment: I think partial application deserves a bit more coverage in the answer. It's pure accident that the OP used `let sampleFunction1 x = ...` rather than `let sampleFunction1 x y = ...` as an example, and that the C# equivalent to the latter would be `Func<int, Func<int, int>>` rather than `Func<int, int, int>` is definitely.. notable, to say the least.

Comment: Well, I can't just copy&paste the whole contents of http://fsharpforfunandprofit.org into the answer. Had to choose something.

Comment: F# has nulls and mutability too.

Comment: There is a difference between allowing and forcing.